# Updating sqlite file without schema changes of an existing app

Tags: ios, sqlite

I already have an existing app on the App Store which has a SQLite file. 
In my next release I want to just update the SQLite file without changing the schema. I just added more number cities than I had previously.

I downloaded the old app from App Store. Open it and push it to background. Now I open Xcode which has new SQLite file and run the code. The app crashes giving a weird error about the schema changes. Not sure why. Error is below.

```
The database at /var/mobile/Applications/9C7203DF-770E-419F-B257-ABF769E8210D/Documents/Mydatabase.sqlite is corrupted.  SQLite error code:11, 'database disk image is malformed'
```

After few other lines of logs. I get the below where it crashes.

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+entityForName: nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter searching for entity name ‘XXXGMOriginAndDestination''
*** First throw call stack:
(0x2d7f8ecb 0x37f93ce7 0x2d549483 0x1e84d9 0x1e6e49 0x447559 0x446a25 0x43e8d1 0x441bef 0x30099ca1 0x300995f3 0x30093ca9 0x3002fc77 0x3002edd9 0x300933e5 0x3269cb55 0x3269c73f 0x2d7c3807 0x2d7c37a3 0x2d7c1f6f 0x2d72c729 0x2d72c50b 0x3009260b 0x3008d871 0x11709f 0x38491ab7)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

It Crashes the app only the first time when it is upgrading the app. It works fine once restarted.

Comment: Are you using Core Data? You shouldn't be updating the SQLite file yourself if so.

Comment: I have a separate target that creates my .sqlite file using coredata. The same file is copied to bundle and used by the app.

Comment: Does this have something to do with .sqlite-shm & .sqlite-wal files?

Comment: Yes. SQLite creates a list of "diffs" and occasionally commits them back to the main SQLite file.

Comment: @Stephen, So how can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You should read this article on the developer site.
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1809/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40014115

> The default journaling mode for Core Data SQLite stores was changed to
>   Write-Ahead Logging (WAL) in iOS 7 and OS X Mavericks. With the WAL
>   mode, Core Data keeps the main store file untouched and appends
>   transactions to a -wal file in the same location. After the Core Data
>   context is saved, the -wal file is not deleted, and the data in that
>   file is not merged to the store file either. Therefore, simply making
>   copies of the store file will likely cause data loss and
>   inconsistency.
>            Change to rollback journaling mode when adding the store to a persistent store coordinator if you have to copy the store file.

I use these options when creating the sqlite database. When I do this, there is only one file created. If you use this file in your new app version, it should work. You might have to version you momd, but I don’t think you will. This presumes that you haven’t moved the original sqlite file from the Documents folder.

```
NSDictionary *options = @{
                                  NSSQLitePragmasOption:@{@"journal_mode":@"DELETE"}, // For creation only
                                  NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption: @YES,
                                  NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption: @YES};
```

Answer (score 0):

While removing the db file, i also removed the -wal & -shm file like so. This worked for me.

```
[fileManager removeItemAtPath:writableDBPath error:&error];
[fileManager removeItemAtPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-wal",writableDBPath] error:&error];
[fileManager removeItemAtPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-shm",writableDBPath] error:&error];
```

Also

Incrementing the number on XXXX.xcdatamodeld file has also fixed it for me.